# C++ cli альтернатива clock() ("time.h)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, время, c++-cli

Пытаюсь переписать код на C++ в VS2019 , но столкнулся с проблемой - библиотека "time.h" и "ctime" не поддерживается, а альтернативу clock() я сам найти не смог. Подскажите, на что можно заменить clock() или как можно подключить библиотеку "time.h"?

```
  private: System::Void timer1_Tick(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {

        timer1->Start();

        timer1->Enabled = true;

        if (int(clock()) / 10 <= D_y)

            if (Math::Abs((int(clock() / 10) * k) - int(int(clock() / 10) * k)) < 0.000001) {

                if (int(int(clock())*k) == 10) {

                    timer1->Enabled = false;

                    button1->Enabled = false;
                }

                if (int(int(clock() / 10) * k) == 0) {

                    timer1->Enabled = false;

                    button1->Enabled = false;
                }

                Build_Graph(int(clock() / 10));

                toolStripLabel1->Text = "Время- " + Convert::ToString(int(clock() / 10 * k)) + " сек ";

                toolStripLabel2->Text = " количество итераций - " + Convert::ToString(int(clock() / 10));

            }
    }
```

Comment: "time.h" и "ctime" это не библиотеки, а заголовочные файлы из стандартной библиотеки, которые всегда на месте. А еще похоже, что вы используете не C++, а C++-cli

Comment: У вас не приведены ни сами ошибки, ни пример для их воспроизведения.

Comment: @VTT , Да, я использую C++ cli, забыл уточнить. Ошибки :  Не удается открыть источник файл "correct.h", "time.h", "crtdbg.h". Это при подключении "ctime"

Comment: Покажите свой код, как и где именно подключаете хедеры. В C++/CLI не должно быть с ними проблем.

Comment: Раз уж вы взяли _управляемую_ версию языка, то следует использовать классы из состава .NET Framework: [Stopwatch](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8), [DateTime](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.8), [TimeSpan](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.8) и т. д.